# Transfer website from weebly to bluehost

Tags: html, forms, server, element, hosts

I am in the process of transferring a website that I've created on Weebly.com to Bluehost. This is not an ideal situation I know but certain circumstances have required it.

The website is very small, 5 pages total. I did all the design on Weebly.com then I archived it and uploaded it to Bluehost.

After a couple of small problems with the pictures I got everything working.
Then I went to the Contact page and tried to fill in the form that sends me email.

It works on the Weebly hosted website but not in the Bluehost website.

Here is the Weebly hosted website version

http://peterevansphoto.weebly.com/contact.html

and here is the Bluehosted website

http://www.peterevansphotography.com/contact.html

With my very limited knowledge of HTML it seems that these lines are where my problem lies.

```
</div>
                <div style="text-align:left; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px;">
                    <input type="hidden" name="form_version" value="2" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="wsite_approved" id="wsite-approved" value="approved" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="ucfid" value="860118176494982449" />
                    <input type='submit' style='position:absolute;top:0;left:-9999px;width:1px;height:1px' /><a class='wsite-button' onclick="document.getElementById('form-860118176494982449').submit()"><span class='wsite-button-inner'>Submit</span></a>
                div/>
```

I guess form-860118176494982449 is not on the Bluehost website but other than that I'm lost.
Thanks for any help

Comment: It's not ideal, but if it helps, Weebly allow you to point your custom domain at your site which would negate this issue entirely. More details [here](https://hc.weebly.com/hc/en-us/articles/201372693-How-to-Use-a-Domain-You-Purchased-Elsewhere).

Answer (score 0):

Weebly handles forms using their own service that only works on Weebly's system. You'll have to create or find some form of form handler yourself (no pun intended!)

I believe that BlueHost offer this option under a link labelled CGI Center in your control panel. There are further details on [their support center](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/249). Hope this helps!